# Can wildcard and single domain certificate coexist for the same domain

Tags: ssl, wildcard-subdomain, ssl-certificate

Because we have externally hosted applications by vendors under specific sub-domains (**vendor1**.domain.org, **vendor2**.domain.org...), we would like to keep single certificates for these sub-domains while having all internally hosted applications in our environment managed by a wildcard certificate under the same *.domain.org domain name but on different servers (**internal1**.domain.org, **internal2**.domain.org...).

Is there any chance for the wildcard certificate creating a conflict with the other sub-domain single certificates already in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can work fine, you just need to use the correct certificate for the correct IP address when configuring the various sites.  The certificates won't "conflict" as they have no idea of each others' existence.  They will each simply be bound to an associated IP on their respective servers.